# Time-dependent Canonical transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, canonical-conjugation

Suppose that the Hamiltonian of the mechanical system under analysis depends on two complex conjugate variables $a$ and $a^*$, so we have:
$$
    H=H\left(a,a^*\right)
$$
Hamilton equations read
$$
   i\,\dot{a}= \frac{\partial H}{\partial a^* }, \qquad i\,\dot{a}^* = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial a}
$$
because the following Poisson bracket holds:
$$
  \{a,a^*\}=-i
$$
Now let us assume to enact the following canonical transformation:
$$
   a \, \to \, \alpha\,e^{-i\omega t}
$$
How does the Hamiltonian modifies? In other words, which is the expression of 
$\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}(\alpha,\alpha^*)$
I'm particularly interested in the additive constant term that shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is a generating function of the $F_2$ type:
$$
F_2=a \alpha^* e^{-i\omega t}
$$
which produces the canonical transformation
$$
a=\alpha e^{-i\omega t}\, .
$$
The Kamiltonian is then
\begin{align}
K&=H(\alpha,\alpha^*)+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial t}\, ,\tag{1}\\
&= H(\alpha,\alpha^*)-i\omega \alpha \alpha^*.
\end{align}
I’m not too sure about the “i” in the last factor as it could be an artefact of using complex coordinates, so you might want to check if the canonical transformation formalism changes Eq.(1) in some way with complex coordinates.